# Can't connect php to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make simple register/login form using PHP and MYSQL. But when I open the website there is a sign saying

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in D:\xampp\htdocs\reg\server.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in D:\xampp\htdocs\reg\server.php on line 10
> Login

Actually I've searched for answers on google but nothing works. Here's the 10th line from the code which comes the error from

```
    // connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'registration');
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you edited this line and sent here?

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'registration');
```

or sent it without edits?

you must change "localhost" to your db host. username to your DB username, and password to your DB password

Comment: It was probably redacted by OP...

Comment: @Dharman what does OP means? :/

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/op/